# INSERT into a table using a select statement for 1 of the columns. All other columns are predefined

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert into a table with set values for all the columns except 1. On the final column I want to loop through a column from another table with a select statement.

```
INSERT INTO bla_bla 
SELECT "PRE", "DEFINED", col1
FROM table_2
```

Comment: Can you give an example? You need to include some more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into tbl1 (col1, col2, col3,....,coln)
select val1, val2, val3,...,valn
from tbl2;
```

Comment: Thanks I worked out I was being stupid shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO your_table ( column1, column2, column3 )
SELECT 'Fixed value 1',
       'Fixed value 2',
       column_from_other_table
FROM   other_table;
```